# Проблемма с Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

Хотел выгрузить проект на Гит, что-то понажимал и теперь всегда такие разноцветные полоски по бокам, как их выключить? Кто-то сталкивался с этим?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: как вы хотели что бы я задал вопрос?

Comment: в соответствии с тем, как написано в справке. Начиная с заголовка и заканчивая содержанием.

Comment: На сколько я понимаю, эти полоски от git. Зеленое - новые строки кода, синиее - модифицированные строки коды. Т.е. показывает вам, что поменялось от последнего коммита

Comment: да да, как это убрать не знаете?

Comment: Делаете коммит - полоски уходят. Отключать это не нужно, это наоборот удобно - видеть что поменялось с предыдущего коммита.

Comment: спасибо за обьяснение